# Xlib XSendEvent Custom ClientEvent

Tags: c, xlib

I'm having problem of sending my program specific event with XSendEvent().
I setup XEvent as follows and send it:

```
XEvent evt;
evt.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
evt.xclient.serial = 0;
evt.xclient.send_event = true;
evt.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom(xconn, "_APP_EVT", false);
evt.xclient.format = 32;
evt.xclient.window = xwin;
evt.xclient.data.l[0] = XInternAtom(xconn, "_APP_EVT_PTR", false);
*reinterpet_cast<void**>(evt.xclient.data.l+1) = <pointer_value>
XSendEvent(xconn, xwin, false, NoEventMask, &evt);
```

Later in event loop I try read the sent pointer from the 
recived message, but the read pointer value is always bad.
So far I have no idea why Xlib even mangles the evt.xclient.data.l array,
since on XLib documentation says X won't interpet the data at all.

```
for(;;) {
    XEvent evt;
    XNextEvent(xconn, &evt);
    if(evt.type == ClientMessage) {
        if(evt.xclient.message_type == XInternAtom(xconn, "_APP_EVT", false)) {
            if(evt.xclient.data.l[0] == XInternAtom(xconn, "_APP_EVT_PTR", false)) {
                // Prints pointers,
                // that have only partially corrects bits in place:
                printf("_APP_EVT_PTR:%p", *reinterpet_cast<void**>(evt.xclient.data.l+1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Another detail here is that the message is sent from main thread,
and the message loop is in separate GUI thread.
I call XInitThreads() on the program before doing anything else with Xlib.

Comment: I managed to fix this bug: it was combination of unsynchronized call to XSendEvent() and reinterpet_cast<>. I protected the XSendEvent with mutex and replaced the cast with `union { long d[2]; uintptr_t ptr; };` field accesses.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to use X11 protocol to implement thread message passing: having to go through the X11 server would hurt performances (especially for non local one, but in 2019 who care).

Comment: @YannDroneaud This is bit of special case as I use the message as round-trip fence: GUI thread signals the fence once it arrives. This guarantees all previous events have been processed by X. No need to stall other windows.

Comment: would `XSync(, False);` does the trick ?

Comment: Actually no, as I need to wait also for the GUI thread finnish processing previous events. Sorry, I noted incorrectly that only X has processed the previous events, I meant X *and* GUI thread have processed previous events.